# How to call action method or function when app is in background

Tags: ios

I am creating app for motion detecting in device. when app is in foreground motion detecting method is used to call and work. But when app is in Background then it is not working. swift

Comment: Thanks to correct me - Moritz

Comment: Hello Every one, I am using CMMotionManager to identify the device position change. so when device position change then i am playing a alarm. it is fine untill when app is in foreground , when app reach in the background thenCMMotionManager is used to stop find the position. Any one have solution please update. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
var backGroundTask : UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid

Add the observer when app will enter the back ground.
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(registerBackGroundTask), name: NSNotification.Name.UIApplicationDidEnterBackground, object: nil)

NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(appDidBecameActive), name: NSNotification.Name.UIApplicationDidBecomeActive, object: nil)

@objc func registerBackGroundTask () {
    backGroundTask = UIApplication.shared.beginBackgroundTask(expirationHandler: {
        self.endBackgroundTask()
    })
    assert(backGroundTask != UIBackgroundTaskInvalid)
}

@objc func endBackgroundTask() {
    UIApplication.shared.endBackgroundTask(backGroundTask)
    backGroundTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid
}


@objc func appDidEnteredBackground() {
    let deadlineTime = DispatchTime.now() + .seconds(countTime)
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: deadlineTime) {
        if (self.activateButton?.isSelected)! {
           self.startDetectingMotion()
        }

    }
}
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(appDidBecameActive), name: NSNotification.Name.UIApplicationDidBecomeActive, object: nil)
 @objc func appDidBecameActive() {
     motionManager.stopDeviceMotionUpdates()
}

When u will start task in background then u have to stop after complete the task. 
This code will be valid only when your app is like background music play app, news app, any IOT device app. if it is not type this app apple will reject the app.
```

Comment: This is working for me, i used this code for accelometer data when app is in background.

Answer (score -1):

DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
    func yourFunction(){}

}